# making simple object inside an object of class into an Object of class

Tags: javascript

I have a class `Todolist` that has objects of `Projects` class inside it.

I have created an object of `Todolist` and saved it to my localStorage.

```
static SaveDate(data) {
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

here `data` is an object of class Todolist.

When I try to get back my data from local storage and save it into a new object of class Todolist.

```
static getData() {
    const Todo = Object.assign(
        new Todolist(),
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"))
    )
    return Todo;
}
```

I get a new Object of class Todolist and I can use its methods but I am not able to use the method of `Project` inside `Todolist` object. They are simple `function objects` not objects of a class `Project`.

How can I make them objects of the class Project?

Comment: So why do you create new `Todolist` instead of a new `Project`?

Comment: To store all Projects inside Todolist. Manage my projects from there.. Like I can delete an project create new project, don't allow project with same name.

Comment: You can't just use assign, you will want to load the data using `JSON.parse`, iterate and create the Project classes from this.  JSON has zero knowledge about classes so there no way to serialise this automatially.

Comment: So firstly i need to load data from local storage into a object than iterate over the object and in the process create new object of the class and add them to ```todolist``` class

Comment: If a `Todolist` contains a `Project`, the `Todolist.getData` method should call the static `Project.getData` method that would be responsible for creating a `new Project` instance from the raw JSON data. (Btw it's customary to call this method `fromJSON` and pass the raw object as an argument)

Comment: is there a way by which we iterate over ```JSON object``` and create this ```project``` objects from that. After that it will be easy just to ```push``` this ```new Project``` to the ```new Todolist``` and return it.